# Extended Properties not in Visual Studio DB Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, extended-properties

Maybe it's me, hopefully I am missing something.

I added some Extended Properties to tables and columns in my MSSQL 2008 database. In Visual Studio 2010 I created a new database project, ran a "schema comparison" to load the DB into my project, and it didn't pick up the Extended Properties.

Can anyone comment on what I might have done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe extended properties are ignored by default in schema comparisons.  You can include them by opening the "Schema Compare Options" dialog, select the Object Types tab, and ensure the Extended Properties checkbox is checked.  Click OK.  The comparison should now include extended properties.

You can also change the default settings for subsequently created comparisons by going to Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Schema Compare.  That'll give you the same dialog as above.

Comment: Unfortunately, [default options for schema compare have been removed in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19758972/3271599)